# Copying the APK to a device fails

Tags: java, android

I just finished my application. But, the problem is, whenever I try to copy the `app-debug.apk` into my smartphone. It fails without any error messages. What causes this problem?

Comment: how do you copy your apk?

Comment: I just copy my apk and then go to the one of folders on my phone and paste it. But it just fails.

Comment: have you tried to install via command line with adb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to install the app, Just run `adb install app-debug.apk` from your command line (Terminal) to install the app